# yn560tx is not connecting to 560iii flashes

Tags: off-camera-flash, yongnuo, wireless-flash

Have anyone ever had a problem with the yn560tx not connecting to the 560iii? It was working at one point of time and the night i used it, it just stopped firing the flashes. I have already tried resetting it to factory mode, changing the channels and groups but nothing has worked.